# How can I capture other computers traffic in Wireshark on a WiFi-network?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark, macbook-air

I run Wireshark on a MacBook Air and I also have a Android phone on the same WiFi-network. If I visit a website with the Android phone I can't see that DNS-traffic (or other traffic) in Wireshark on my MacBook Air. Is there any way I can capture all traffic on the WiFi-network in Wireshark?

Answer (score 1):

You need a network card that can be set in 'promiscuous mode' which I don't believe the MBA allows.

You may have better luck using ADB to get logs via usb debugging in this *specific* case but in general you're going to need different network hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to capture in promiscuous or monitor mode; not all Wi-Fi adapters and their drivers handle promiscuous mode, but many of them handle monitor mode, including the adapters in various flavors of MacBook and the OS X drivers for them.

If the network is encrypted (WEP/WPA), monitor mode traffic will be encrypted, and [you will have to arrange that Wireshark can decrypt it](http://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11).